# How can I access custom CSS property from JavaScript in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I'm using Polymer and would like to be able get the value of a custom CSS property in JavaScript.

I thought I'd be able to do it using `this.customStyle["--my-style"]` but this was not the case (the result is `undefined`). You can see the element below:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    </style>
    <div>Some Content</div>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "my-element",
      attached: function () {
        console.log(this.customStyles["--my-style"])
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Is there anyway I can access this custom style from within the JavaScript - I'm able to set the value, just not retrieve it.

Comment: Where did you define your `--my-style`  CSS property ? Can you try to log it in the ` ready` lifecycle callback ?

Answer (score 1):

`customStyles` is an empty object which you populate while updating the properties. If you need to retrieve any value `Polymer` has provided another api [getComputedStyleValue](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-getComputedStyleValue).

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id='computed-style'>
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        --my-style: red;
      }
      .test {
        color: var(--my-style);
      }
    </style>
    <div class='test' on-tap='getStyle'>Hello</div>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'computed-style',
    getStyle: function() {
      console.log(this.getComputedStyleValue('--my-style'));
    }
  })
</script>


<computed-style></computed-style>
```